# In c# How do I control which Excel opens?

Tags: c#

I have Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 (Via Office 365) on my machine (Windows 7 Home Premium)

Is there a way to control which Excel opens when

```
 var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

Is called?

Thanks for your time,
KW

Comment: what Excel library are you using?  If you are able, you should try doing something like a `Process.Start()` on the absolute path of the excel executable

Comment: @sircapsalot: he wants to automate the COM server. Starting the process won't allow this.

Comment: Does this help? I am using Visual Studio 2013. using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Answer (score 0):

One of possible approaches is to rely on dynamic COM automation:

```
Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgId( "Excel.Application.[v]" );
dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance( excelType );
```

where

`Excel.Application.[v]` is

`Excel.Application.14` or `Excel.Application.15` depending on which version you want to run.

Since `excel` is dynamic, you use it in the same way, despite the actual version:

```
excel.Visible = true;
...
```